# C# Windows Form Application Textboxs gets blurred

Tags: c#

Oddly, my text boxes gets blurred after i did some changes in the form properties. I think that i changed opacity of form due to which this is happening but changed it back, nothing happened. Still stuck in this problem. Tried adding new text boxes. Same problem :(

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG2Nu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have set the form's `TransparencyKey` property to `Black`. This makes everything in your form that is drawn in black color transparent.

Simply change the property to something else, or just set it to `Transparent` to make it only apply to completely transparent colors.

**EDIT:** You can also right-click the `TransparencyKey` property and press `Reset`.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. :) . It worked

Comment: @UsmanAshraf : Good! Please mark my post as the accepted answer by pressing the green check mark on it's left.